# Collapsible Column table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, mean-stack

We want to create the collapsible column table using bootstrap and angularjs.
This collapsing shouldn't be like toggle but rather like vertical accordion.
If any reference of this type of table is available then please provide.

[image]

Comment: yes. you can. according to your requirement change condition. refer https://jsfiddle.net/raz77c61/1/ . It might help you. on click of 2,4,6,8 row it collapse

Comment: @priya_singh thanks for the fiddle but my problem is making whole table column as a shutter.
The hide and show process gives very abrupt execution of the merging.
Also merging the column header is not i require, rather whole column should shut down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-repeat to create tables with single column.

```
<table  ng-repeat="employee in employees track by $index" 
 ng-init="colIndex = $index">
  <tr ng-repeat='info in employee track by $index' 
   ng-init="rowIndex = $index" 
   ng-click="rowIndex === 0 ? clicked(colIndex) : null" >
  </tr>
</table>
```

To see a demo of the collapsible table visit : https://codepen.io/Midhun1993/pen/mRVGjq/